# bloomberg install no access to temp file

Tags: installation, bloomberg

I am receiving this message when installing the Bloomberg professional download.  "The File C:\Users\joshua\AppData\Local\TEmp\install_info.txt"   I cannot find this file in my folder so i am not sure how to provide the bloomberg install program with access.

Comment: Have you asked Bloomberg?

Comment: yes but they could not fix it.  ultimately i figured out that i needed to change the permission of the bloomberg destination folder and then reinstalled the necessary addin

Answer (score -1):

I've had this error, and I have resolved this issue by clean regedit from Bloomberg, make a search, and voila